# Why does MSVC not inline variable names in the generated assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly, visual-c++, x86-64, masm

When compiling the program beneath to assembly using MSVC:

```c
int main() {int var1 = 1; int var2 = 2;}
```

Then the generated assembly code will look like this:

```
var1$ = 0
var2$ = 4

main    PROC
    sub rsp, 24
    mov DWORD PTR var1$[rsp], 1
    mov DWORD PTR var2$[rsp], 2
    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 24
    ret 0
main    ENDP
```

I'm wondering why the `var1$ = 0` and `var2$ = 4` is necessary since the it could be avoided by inlining it in the `mov` as such: `mov DWORD PTR [rsp], 1` and `mov DWORD PTR [rsp + 4], 2`. This results in a smaller assembly, and maybe also a smaller .obj and .exe file.
I'm compiling using `CL Test.c /Fa`

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: The generated machine code between the assembler given and the suggestion you made will be the same, the code given is just a bit easier to follow: var2$ is easier to understand than just the number 4.

Comment: `var1$ = 0` is more or less the assembly equivalence of C's `#define var1 0`.

Comment: So the assembler will handle it and perhaps inline it?

Comment: @ChristofferHansen the assembler won't inline anything. `mov DWORD PTR var1$[rsp], 1` is strictly the exact same thing as `mov DWORD PTR 0[rsp], 1`

Comment: Ok, I thought `var1$ = 0` would require memory to store.

Comment: Yeah, `var2$ = 4` defines an **assemble-time constant**.  That's the asm equivalent of `#define` in C.  (Well sort of; it's evaluated to a number on the spot, not just a text substitution),

Comment: @ChristofferHansen no, see my 1st comment

Comment: Great, that explains it. Thanks!

Comment: Note that MSVC's asm output is *not* part of the normal compilation process.  It normally emits instructions as machine code, not asm text.  It only emits text if you specifically ask it to do that instead of making machine code.  So it makes sense for it to be verbose by default.  (Unlike GCC where you have to use `-fverbose-asm` to comment the asm with C var names if you want that.)

Comment: Surely `var1$ = 0` doesn't allocate memory, because `[[memory]][register]` is not a valid addressing mode.